# VBA Macro: Validation not recognized

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a dropdown list but the `error 1004 'Application-defined or object-defined error'` comes up at the `.add` function all the way to `Formula1`.

I have tried:

- removing `offset(0,3)`
- Having it all in one line
- Removing the brackets and moving the '.Add' to the next line
- Copying working Validation functions that I found online

I have no idea what is wrong. I think it might not be recognized but I am unsure.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Offset(0, 3).Select
MsgBox cell

With Selection.Validation.Add(Type:=xlValidateList, _
                              AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                              Operator:=xlBetween, _
                              Formula1:="B2:B5")
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

Comment: If you are using hard-coded ranges, then why the `Offset()`?? Any why use `.Select` when you can declare a range var?

Comment: try: `Formula1:="=$B$2:$B$5"`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I am doing a loop but I got the error so I decided to focus on the exact error and use hard-coded ranges instead

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I just tried that, still the same error, but thanks, that might of fixed a future one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.Add` in your `With Block`.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C2").Offset(0, 3).Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$2:$B$5"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

And I would suggest avoiding `.Select` and declare your range variables.

```
Dim myRng As Range
Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F2")

With myRng.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$2:$B$5"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

---

It probably wouldn't be a bad idea to ensure that you don't currently have validation set there using `.delete` - it may throw an error if you already have data validation set from a prior attempt.

```
With myRng.Validation
    .delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$2:$B$5"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

Comment: I still got the error for .Add, I am not sure what you mean by not having .Add in my With block? Just not have it in the same line?

Comment: See my edit about `.delete`. This was tested and works - except when I already had validation there.

Comment: @K.Davis yes it worked! The cell I was checking was empty and had no validation but the `.delete` fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help @efoc!